# Group By Except For Certain Value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to create a (sqlite) query that will perform a GROUP BY but will not group anything with the value 'unknown'.  For example, I have the table:

```
id |   name  | parent_id | school_id |
 1 | john    |   1       |    1      |
 2 | john    |   1       |    1      |
 3 | john    |   1       |    1      |
 4 | nick    |   2       |    2      |
 5 | nick    |   2       |    2      |
 6 | nick    |   3       |    3      |
 7 | bob     |   4       |    4      |
 8 | unknown |   5       |    5      |
 9 | unknown |   5       |    5      |
 10| unknown |   5       |    5      |
```

With the proper query with 'GROUP BY name, parent_id, school_id' I need the following rows returned:

```
id |   name  | parent_id | school_id |
 1 | john    |   1       |    1      |
 3 | nick    |   2       |    2      |
 4 | nick    |   3       |    3      |
 5 | bob     |   4       |    4      |
 6 | unknown |   5       |    5      |
 7 | unknown |   5       |    5      |
 8 | unknown |   5       |    5      |
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Answer added avoiding GROUP BY and the cost of parsing the table twice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't easily do this with one statement but you can `UNION` the results of two statements

- `GROUP` the list of all *but* `unknown`
- Add (`UNION`) the list of all `unknown`

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT MIN(id), name, parent_id, school_id
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  name <> 'unknown'
GROUP BY
       name, parent_id, school_id
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, parent_id, school_id
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  name = 'unknown'
```

*Note that I assume you have posted wrong `unknown` id's in your result*

Comment: @Rahul - printed and framed on wall :)

Answer (score 4):

As a single query...

```
SELECT
  MIN(id)            AS id,
  name,
  parent_id,
  school_id
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  CASE WHEN name = 'unknown' THEN id ELSE 0 END,
  name,
  parent_id,
  school_id
```

Or possibly...

```
GROUP BY
  CASE WHEN name <> 'unknown' THEN name ELSE CAST(id AS VARCHAR(???)) END,
  parent_id,
  school_id

-- Where VARCHAR(???) is the data type of the `name` field.
-- Also assumes no value in `name` is the same as an id for an 'unknown' field
```

Both avoid UNION and the overhead of parsing the table twice, replacing it with a slightly increased complexity `GROUP BY`.

Comment: +1 Afaik, this would work in SQL Server but does SQLLite allow it?

Comment: @Lieven - I don't know tbh, it would need testing.  Other than syntax discrepancies, this doesn't break anything according to ANSI SQL.  I'd hope it works, it's not a complex query...

Comment: Not complex but not something that comes immediately to mind. I'm not sure about the cost though: the UNION *can* use indexes while the CASE is a full table scan. OP would have to compare execution plans to verify what performs best.

Comment: @Lieven - That's why I made the last sentence a cop-out.  I don't know the cost or how SQLite will behave.  The UNION is two INDEX SCANs, and this is *probably*, as you say, a TABLE SCAN.  Depending on the native order of the data, the sorting phase may be simple, or not.  In the UNION version, unless there is a covering index in the correct order, a sort will still be required.  Me, I'd just test both on as large a representative sample set as I could reliable create.  I don't trust anyone's ideas or judgements, not even my own :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  MIN(id), name, parent_id, school_id
  FROM  Table
WHERE   name <> 'unknown'
GROUP BY name, parent_id, school_id
UNION ALL
SELECT  id, name, parent_id, school_id
  FROM  Table
 WHERE  name = 'unknown'
```

Comment: yea ... but i like your answer ... you did explain Nick how to go about the query :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  MIN(id) AS id,
  IF(tmpname=id,"unknown",tmpname) AS name,
  parent_id,
  school_id
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id,parent_id,school_id
    IF(name="unknown",id,name) AS tmpname
  FROM <tablename>
) AS baseview
GROUP BY tmpname
```

Comment: +1 Intriguing but you should group on parent_id & school_id and you can't to my knowledge check for `tmpname=id` in your outer select.

Comment: Should be tmpid the same way as tmpname - sorry

Comment: @Lievent - Agreed, need to add those two field to the GROUP BY, then change the `id` in the first IF() block to `MIN(id)`.  I'd also explicitly cast the integer to a varchar(), so as to avoid ambiguity and the possibility to it trying to cast the varchar() to an integer.  [In both IF() blocks.]