# Grouping and chunking by value in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple raw SQL query which is returning data like this:

```
SELECT
   a.id, count(ah.id) as count 
FROM 
  `table_name_one` as a 
JOIN 
  `table_name_two` as ah 
ON 
  a.id=ah.answer_id 
WHERE 
  a.user_id = 7178 
  AND a.created_at BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-28' 
GROUP BY a.id
```

[image]

I want to group this result by two groups. 
Group One will contain data when revisionCount == 1 and Group Two will contain rest of the data. I can do this by using a loop but if I can do this by SQL query it will be good for me.

Can anybody help me out from here?

Comment: Here is link which can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610907/group-by-except-for-certain-value

Comment: change only **GROUP BY a.id** to GROUP BY (revisionCount = 1) desc ,a.id**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to construct a list of the two sets of values, you can do so in one query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN cnt = 1 THEN id END) as id_1s,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN cnt > 1 THEN id END) as id_2plus
FROM (SELECT a.id, count(ah.id) as cnt 
      FROM `table_name_one` a JOIN 
           `table_name_two` as ah 
           ON a.id = ah.answer_id 
      WHERE a.user_id = 7178 AND
            a.created_at BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-28' 
      GROUP BY a.id
     ) a;
```

This puts the values into comma-delimited lists.  MySQL by default limits the length to 1,024 characters.  If the lists are longer, then you can run the query twice to generate each . . . or just order by `cnt` and check the value when you are reading the return values.

Comment: Yes, this return comma-delimited list. But I need data like this format
array:2 [▼
  0 => {
      0 => {
       +"id": 171437
       +"revisionCount": 1
     }, 
     1 => {
       +"id": 171437
       +"revisionCount": 1
     }
  1 => {#671 ▼
    +"id": 172759
    +"revisionCount": 2
  }
.....
]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `having` clause to achieve this. I would recommend you to read online for more info on `having`.

Below query will give you all records with count exactly as 1:

```
SELECT
   a.id, count(ah.id) as count 
FROM 
  `table_name_one` as a 
JOIN 
  `table_name_two` as ah 
ON 
  a.id=ah.answer_id 
WHERE 
  a.user_id = 7178 
  AND a.created_at BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-28' 
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING count(ah.id) = 1
```

You can tweak the having condition in the above query to get the second set.

Comment: This will return data where count == 1. But I need all data in two array.

Comment: To have it in the same query, you can use `CASE WHEN` clause to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need 2 result sets as arrays in php, for which you need to write 2 queries separated by semicolon.

```
Query 1 where revision count =1;
Query 2 where revision count >1;
```

Hope this helps