# How to output rows containing a combined total based on another column's value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have this query which results in rows containing an order total and the customer ID.

```
SELECT postMetaOrderTotal.meta_value as 'order_total', postMetaCustomerUser.meta_value as 'customer_user' FROM wp_posts as posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as postMetaOrderTotal ON postMetaOrderTotal.post_id=posts.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as postMetaCustomerUser ON postMetaCustomerUser.post_id=posts.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_users as users ON users.ID = postMetaCustomerUser.meta_value
WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'  
AND postMetaOrderTotal.meta_key = '_order_total' 
AND postMetaCustomerUser.meta_key = '_customer_user'
```

Results are:

[image]

How can I get the results to be the total for each customer user? (e.g. in screenshot, customer 74's 2 rows would be 1 with a combined order total)?

I have looked into GROUP BY statements (https://www.guru99.com/group-by.html) and grouping by `customer_user` but these result in 1 row for the customer 0

Comment: What do you expect for customer 0? No grouping?

Comment: Move the last two conditions to their respective JOIN...ON clauses

Comment: You can't do it with a single query, but with a union query it's possible. Check this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610907/group-by-except-for-certain-value

Comment: @EliasSoares A UNION IS a single query. !?!

Comment: @Strawberry you got what I mean. A single select.

Answer (score -1):

you can use group by customer_user and then sum the order_total like:

```
SELECT SUM(postMetaOrderTotal.meta_value) as 'order_total', postMetaCustomerUser.meta_value as 'customer_user' 
FROM wp_posts as posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as postMetaOrderTotal ON postMetaOrderTotal.post_id=posts.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as postMetaCustomerUser ON postMetaCustomerUser.post_id=posts.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_users as users ON users.ID = postMetaCustomerUser.meta_value
WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'  
AND postMetaOrderTotal.meta_key = '_order_total' 
AND postMetaCustomerUser.meta_key = '_customer_user' GROUP BY postMetaCustomerUser.meta_value
```

Comment: The op doesn't want to group when customer is zero. Your answer do not solve this.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly you could use `SUM` and `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT customer_user, SUM(order_total) GROUP BY custom_user;
```

So with your original query something like this could work :

```
SELECT SUM(postMetaOrderTotal.meta_value) as 'order_total', postMetaCustomerUser.meta_value as 'customer_user' 
FROM wp_posts as posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as postMetaOrderTotal ON postMetaOrderTotal.post_id=posts.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as postMetaCustomerUser ON postMetaCustomerUser.post_id=posts.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_users as users ON users.ID = postMetaCustomerUser.meta_value
WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'  
AND postMetaOrderTotal.meta_key = '_order_total' 
AND postMetaCustomerUser.meta_key = '_customer_user'
GROUP BY custom_user;
```

If you want to exclude customer 0 totally then just use a `WHERE`.
If you don't want to customer 0 's data, you'll have to use `UNION`.

Comment: The op doesn't want to group when customer is zero. Your answer do not solve this.

Comment: I misunderstood the original post, edited, thanks !